# pdo lastInsertId() keeps returning 0

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two queries that insert data to their respective tables. That works fine. What I have been trying to do is get the lastInsertId after each query is executed and insert those values into a third table. However, when I check the database, the value 0 is entered. Both tables have an auto-incremented field. Can you tell by my code why that is happening or have any suggestions? I'm relatively new to php so if you notice the way I'm coding is untidy, particularly at the end where I execute the queries, please tell me. I'd appreciate it.

```
if ($oneWay)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO journey
        (from_destination,to_destination,journey_type,depart_date,depart_time,seats_available,journey_message,user_type)
        VALUES('$pjFrom','$pjTo','$radioJourneyType', STR_TO_DATE('$departDate','%d/%m/%Y'),'$newDepTime','$seatcounter','$textareanotes','$radUserType')";
        $userID = "SELECT user_id FROM `user` ORDER BY journey_id DESC LIMIT 1";
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO journey
        (from_destination,to_destination,journey_type,depart_date,depart_time,return_date,return_time,seats_available,journey_message,user_type)
        VALUES('$pjFrom','$pjTo','$radioJourneyType', STR_TO_DATE('$departDate','%d/%m/%Y'),'$newDepTime',STR_TO_DATE('$returnDate','%d/%m/%Y'),'$newRetTime ','$seatcounter','$textareanotes','$radUserType')";
        //$userID = "SELECT user_id FROM `user` ORDER BY journey_id DESC LIMIT 1";
    }
    $queryfb = "INSERT INTO user
        (facebook_id,facebook_username,facebook_first_name,facebook_last_name,facebook_image,facebook_link)
        VALUES('$hdnFacebookId','$hdnUsername','$hdnFirstName','$hdnLastName','$hdnFacebookImg','$hdnFacebookUrl')";
        //$journeyID = "SELECT journey_id FROM `journey` ORDER BY journey_id DESC LIMIT 1";

    $queryUserJourney = "INSERT INTO user_journey
                        (user_id,journey_id)
                        VALUES('$lastUserID','$lastJourneyID')";

    $db->exec($query);
    $lastUserID = $db->lastInsertId();
    $db->exec($queryfb);
    $lastJourneyID = $db->lastInsertId();
    $db->exec($queryUserJourney);//problem: 0 values being entered???
}
```

Updated

```
$db->exec($query);
    $lastUserID = $db->lastInsertId();
    $db->exec($queryfb);
    $lastJourneyID = $db->lastInsertId();
    $queryUserJourney = "INSERT INTO user_journey
                        (user_id,journey_id)
                        VALUES('$lastUserID','$lastJourneyID')";
    $db->exec($queryUserJourney);working thanks to jmadsen
```

Comment: PHP's string interpolation doesn't work as you believe it does. You can't just replace a variable used to compose the string and expect the string to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I've had my coffee - you are creating the last insert statement BEFORE you populate the variables. I think this is what Maerlyn was hinting at

You need to move $queryUserJourney down below your 2 inserts.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance jmadsen and good morning. Now I can go to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try

```
$db->lastInsertId();
```

... instead. Note the lowercase `d` in `lastInsertId`.

[Reference doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: I typed ID by mistake in the question. Updated that little error. I use $lastUserID = $db->lastInsertId(); as I want to insert that variable along with the other into a third table.

Answer (score 0):

@Colin,

PDO's last insert id returns the value of an auto-increment primary key, if I'm not completely mistaken. It looks to me like $query's table doesn't have this

Comment: It's possible that this is the case, but since @colin-roe used `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES` (instead of `INSERT INTO table VALUES...`), you can't know for sure the table schema.

Comment: that's right, but since the inserts are working, but Insert Id's are zero, I'm gonna stick with my answer :-) Surprised the capitalization problem doesn't through an error, though

Comment: I have the auto-incremented primary key field in the table. You don't include that in the query as it's auto-incremeted anyway. I choose to have both the column names and the values to be inserted out of habit using SQL.